# Http 416, Requested range not satisfiable

Tags: java, jsoup, httpclient

I'm using http client to get data:

```
public static String getHttpResponse(String url) {

//LOGGER.info("Download page context from URL " + url);
String httpClientResponse = null;
try {
  URI uri = new URIBuilder(url).build();
  HttpResponse response;

  HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost());
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);

  //request.setConfig(config);
  request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"));
  request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "text/html"));
  request.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes=100-1500");

  org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
      client = HttpClients.custom().build();

  response = client.execute(target, request);

  //LOGGER.info("Status Line for URL {} is {}", uri.getHost() + File.separator + uri.getPath(), response.getStatusLine());

  InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

  if (inputStream == null || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    /*LOGGER.error("Non-success response while downloading image. Response {}", response.getStatusLine());
    LOGGER.error("Error while download data from url {}", url);*/
  } else {
    httpClientResponse = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error while download content from URL");
}
return httpClientResponse;
}
```

Also: Can we do this using Jsoup?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but what range of bytes should I give?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
request.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes=100-1500");
```

with:

```
request.addHeader("Range", "bytes=100-1500");
```

The `Accept-Ranges` header is part of server response, which indicates that the server accepts partial requests.

In your request you should use `Range` header, which indicates which part of document server should return.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range